# Populate dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of strings (from a `.tt` file) that looks like this:

```
list1 = ['have\tVERB', 'and\tCONJ', ..., 'tree\tNOUN', 'go\tVERB']
```

I want to turn it into a dictionary that looks like:

```
dict1 = { 'have':'VERB', 'and':'CONJ', 'tree':'NOUN', 'go':'VERB' }
```

I was thinking of substitution, but it doesn't work that well. Is there a way to tag the tab string `'\t'` as a divider?

Comment: `'have':'VERB'` you mean?

Comment: `dict` keys should be unique

Answer (score 16):

Try the following:

```
dict1 = dict(item.split('\t') for item in list1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>>dict1
{'and': 'CONJ', 'go': 'VERB', 'tree': 'NOUN', 'have': 'VERB'}
```

Comment: <3 Pythonic is the way <3

Comment: `[]` are redundant, generator expression would work just fine and will use less memory in a process.

Answer (score 7):

Since [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) *also* splits on `'\t'` by default (`'\t'` is considered white space), you could get a functional approach by feeding [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) that looks quite elegant:

```
d = dict(map(str.split, list1))
```

With the dictionary `d` now being in the wanted form:

```
print(d)
{'and': 'CONJ', 'go': 'VERB', 'have': 'VERB', 'tree': 'NOUN'}
```

---

If you need a split *only on* `'\t'` (while ignoring `' '` and `'\n'`) and still want to use the `map` approach, you can create a partial object with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) that only uses `'\t'` as the separator:

```
from functools import partial 

# only splits on '\t' ignoring new-lines, white space e.t.c 
tabsplit = partial(str.split, sep='\t')
d = dict(map(tabsplit, list1))
```

this, of course, yields the same result for `d` using the sample list of strings.

Comment: Might be more overtly functional, but this is explicitly not pythonic.

Answer (score 4):

do that with a simple dict comprehension and a `str.split` (without arguments `strip` splits on blanks)

```
list1 = ['have\tVERB', 'and\tCONJ',  'tree\tNOUN', 'go\tVERB']
dict1 = {x.split()[0]:x.split()[1] for x in list1}
```

result:

```
{'and': 'CONJ', 'go': 'VERB', 'tree': 'NOUN', 'have': 'VERB'}
```

EDIT: the `x.split()[0]:x.split()[1]` does `split` twice, which is not optimal. Other answers here do it better without dict comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

A short way to solve the problem, since split method splits `'\t'` by default (as pointed out by Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard), could be:

```
dictionary = dict(item.split() for item in list1)
print dictionary
```

I also wrote down a more simple and classic approach.

Not very pythonic but easy to understand for beginners:

```
list1 = ['have\tVERB', 'and\tCONJ', 'tree\tNOUN', 'go\tVERB']
dictionary1 = {}

for item in list1:
    splitted_item = item.split('\t')
    word = splitted_item[0]
    word_type = splitted_item[1]
    dictionary1[word] = word_type

print dictionary1
```

Here I wrote the same code with very verbose comments:

```
# Let's start with our word list, we'll call it 'list1'

list1 = ['have\tVERB', 'and\tCONJ', 'tree\tNOUN', 'go\tVERB']

# Here's an empty dictionary, 'dictionary1'

dictionary1 = {}

# Let's start to iterate using variable 'item' through 'list1'

for item in list1:

# Here I split item in two parts, passing the '\t' character
# to the split function and put the resulting list of two elements
# into 'splitted_item' variable.
# If you want to know more about split function check the link available
# at the end of this answer

    splitted_item = item.split('\t')

# Just to make code more readable here I now put 1st part
# of the splitted item (part 0 because we start counting
# from number 0) in "word" variable

    word = splitted_item[0]

# I use the same apporach to save the 2nd part of the 
# splitted item into 'word_type' variable
# Yes, you're right: we use 1 because we start counting from 0

    word_type = splitted_item[1]

# Finally I add to 'dictionary1', 'word' key with a value of 'word_type' 

    dictionary1[word] = word_type

# After the for loop has been completed I print the now
# complete dictionary1 to check if result is correct

print dictionary1
```

Useful links:

- You can quickly copy and paste this code here to check how it works and tweak it if you like: http://www.codeskulptor.com
- If you want to learn more about split and string functions in general: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: @lenakmeth
If you found my answer useful please upvote it and / or mark it as solution.
Thanks :)