# python: convert below format type of list in to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert the below type of list to dictionary:

```
input_list = [' test1                                  0', ' test2                     1']

output_dict = {'test1': 0, 'test2': 1}
```

if I input the above list, expecting output in the form of dictionary. The problem is that the input list has got spaces within the object. E.g. there is lot of white spaces between test1 and 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate dictionary from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40767647/populate-dictionary-from-list)

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to get your keys and values from the data.

```
for string in input_list:
    key,value = filter(lambda s: len(s)>0,string.split(' '))
    output_dict[key] = int(value)
print output_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Only a idea, not tested ;)

```
output_dict = {}
for item in input_list:
  kye, value = item.split()
  output_dict[kye] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string to get two items, first one is for key of the dictionary and second one is for the value.

Here is the code:

```
input_list = [' test1                                  0', ' test2                     1']
output_dict = dict()
for single_item in input_list:
    single_item = single_item.strip()
    single_item_ar = single_item.split()
    output_dict[single_item_ar[0]] = int(single_item_ar[1])
print(output_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'test1': 0, 'test2': 1}
```

N.B.: This operation can be done in many ways. It is most trivial and human readable way.